# Not able to change API Name in swagger

Tags: swagger, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

We are using swagger for one of our java rest services , but I am not able to change the API name for those. I tried changing the api names by different ways, but still it is displaying in different format while accessing the swagger-ui.
For eg: if my API name is EmployeeApiService , in swagger-ui, it is displaying as employee-api-service.

Please find the details :

Maven Dependencies: springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swaagger-ui with both as version 2.7.0

Ways I tried:

1). By giving @API annotation with tags i.e.

```
   @Api(value="EmployeeApiService", tags={EmployeeApi})
```

2). By giving @SwaggerDefinition .

In both cases, the api name is not getting changed in swagger UI.

Please help.

Comment: Do you use spring data rest? If yes, did you set the `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "EmployeeApiService", path = "EmployeeApiService")` like this?

Comment: We are using spring with hibernate but not spring data rest. I need to get changed in the swagger ui  only. Current I am implementing swagger for an already developed spring application